# Converting preview frame to bitmap

Tags: android, camera, frame, preview, yuv

I know the subject was on the board many times, but i can not get it work anyhow...
I want to save view frames from preview to jpeg files. It looks more or less(code is simplified- without additional logic, exception etc) like this...

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
  int width = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width;
  int height = camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().height;


  final int[] rgb = decodeYUV420SP(data, width, height);

  Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(rgb, width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

  String filename="/sdcard/file" + (index++)+ ".jpg"; 
  FileOutputStream out;
  out = new FileOutputStream(filename);
  bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
  out.flush();
  out.close();
  out=null;

 }
```

Here is the one of the methods i tried to convert colors(from this board i believe)

```
public int[] decodeYUV420SP( byte[] yuv420sp, int width, int height) {   

    final int frameSize = width * height;   

    int rgb[]=new int[width*height];   
    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {   
        int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;   
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {   
            int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;   
            if (y < 0) y = 0;   
            if ((i & 1) == 0) {   
                v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;   
                u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;   
            }   

            int y1192 = 1192 * y;   
            int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);   
            int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);   
            int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);   

            if (r < 0) r = 0; else if (r > 262143) r = 262143;   
            if (g < 0) g = 0; else if (g > 262143) g = 262143;   
            if (b < 0) b = 0; else if (b > 262143) b = 262143;   

            rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) &    
    0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);   


        }   
    }   
    return rgb;   
    }
```

The problem is that the picture always looks like three 'strange green pictures'...
I ama new user so i can't post it:(

I dont know if it has something to do with the size or what but i am stuck...
Can you support me with it?

Comment: In case it helps, there is discussion about this at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12345415/android-decodeyuv420sp-results-in-green-images/26566778
 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325861/converting-yuv-rgbimage-processing-yuv-during-onpreviewframe-in-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I found out the width and height read from PreviewSize were wrong....
In other words the conversion went wrong because it was based on false values.
After use a new way of setting the preview settings(from example deleivered by google) everything works fine.

EDIT:

Sorry for the quick answer above and long delay.

It was while ago and I can not dig the code now, but i think that I used:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getSupportedPreviewSizes%28%29)

and took the first element from the list and set the values with

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize(int, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPreviewSize%28int,%20int%29)

i stored the width and height and used it to transform picture.

It dont know if it was the best solution, but it worked out.

Comment: It is informative. When you setPreviewSize to value that is not supported it seems to produce garbage.

Answer (score 20):

Alternatively, if you *DO* need a bitmap for some reason, and/or want to do this without creating a YUVImage and compressing to JPEG, you can use the handy RenderScript 'ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB' (API 17+):

```
@Override 
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) { 
   Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(r.width(), r.height(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Allocation bmData = renderScriptNV21ToRGBA8888(
        mContext, r.width(), r.height(), data);
    bmData.copyTo(bitmap);
}

public Allocation renderScriptNV21ToRGBA8888(Context context, int width, int height, byte[] nv21) {
  RenderScript rs = RenderScript.create(context);
  ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB yuvToRgbIntrinsic = ScriptIntrinsicYuvToRGB.create(rs, Element.U8_4(rs));

  Type.Builder yuvType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs)).setX(nv21.length);
  Allocation in = Allocation.createTyped(rs, yuvType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

  Type.Builder rgbaType = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.RGBA_8888(rs)).setX(width).setY(height);
  Allocation out = Allocation.createTyped(rs, rgbaType.create(), Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);

  in.copyFrom(nv21);

  yuvToRgbIntrinsic.setInput(in);
  yuvToRgbIntrinsic.forEach(out);
  return out;
}
```

Comment: What is the 'r' argument in the call to createBitmap?

Comment: My guess for 'r' is the width/heigth you can get by calling `camera.getParameters().getPreviewSize().width` etc.

Comment: I've looked for this answer for a while. This is the best answer, should be accepted.

Answer (score 12):

Simply saving to a jpeg is an easier task than converting to bitmap, no need for that YUV decoding code thanks to `YuvImage` class.

```
import android.graphics.YuvImage; 

@Override 
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) { 
    try { 
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters(); 
        Size size = parameters.getPreviewSize(); 
        YuvImage image = new YuvImage(data, parameters.getPreviewFormat(), 
                size.width, size.height, null); 
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "out.jpg"); 
        FileOutputStream filecon = new FileOutputStream(file); 
        image.compressToJpeg( 
                new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 90, 
                filecon); 
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) { 
        Toast toast = Toast 
                .makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), 1000); 
        toast.show(); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not mistaken, you want the width and height of the picture to decode, not the width and heigth of the preview.

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid degraded JPEG image on the output (e.g. with interleaving green/red spots), you need to **flush** and **close** **FileOutputStream**

```
FileOutputStream filecon = new FileOutputStream(file); 
image.compressToJpeg( 
            new Rect(0, 0, image.getWidth(), image.getHeight()), 90, 
        filecon);
filecon.flush();
filecon.close();
```