# Android - show processed camera preview

Tags: android, augmented-reality, android-camera

i´m trying to create some kind of AR (Augmented Reality), but i don´t know how exactly can I **get preview from phone camera frame by frame**, process each frame as a bitmap and than **show it in my SurfaceView**. My starting point is CameraPreview SDK example.

Can anybody tell me, how to:

**1) get frame/bitmap from camera** (i guess, i´ll need to decode picture from YUV to RGB like here: [Converting preview frame to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768165/android-problem-whith-converting-preview-frame-to-bitmap))

**2) show bitmap (after processing) in a SurfaceView**