# Android YuvImage class format incorrect?

Tags: android, image, camera, preview, yuv

It's well documented that Android's camera preview data is returned back in NV21 (YUV 420).  2.2 added a YuvImage class for decoding the data.  The problem I've encountered is that the YuvImage class data appears corrupt or incorrect.  I used the Renderscript Sample app called HelloCompute which transforms a Bitmap into a mono-chrome Bitmap.  I used two methods for decoding the Preview data into a Bitmap and passing it as input to the Renderscript:

**Method 1 - Android YuvImage Class:**

```
YuvImage preview = new YuvImage(data, ImageFormat.NV21, width, height, null);

ByteArrayOutputStream mJpegOutput = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length); 

preview.compressToJpeg(new Rect(0, 0, width, height), 100, mJpegOutput);
mBitmapIn = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray( mJpegOutput.toByteArray(), 0, mJpegOutput.size());
```

// pass mBitmapIn to RS

**Method 2 - Posted Decoder Method:**
As posted [over here by David Pearlman](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/c85e829ab209ceea/)

```
// work around for Yuv format </p>
mBitmapIn = Bitmap.createBitmap(
      ImageUtil.decodeYUV420SP(data, width, height),
      width, 
      height, 
      Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

// pass mBitmapIn to RS
```

When the image is processed by the Renderscript and displayed Method 1 is very grainy and not mono-chrome, while *Method 2 produces the expected output*, a mono-chrome image of the preview frame.  Am I doing something wrong or is the YuvImage class not usable?  I'm testing this on a Xoom running 3.1.

Furthermore, I displayed the bitmaps produced by both methods on screen prior to passing to the RS.  The bitmap from Method 1 has noticeable differences in lighting (I suspected this was due to the JPeg compression), while Method 2's bitmap is identical to the Preview Frame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no justification for using Jpeg encode/decode just to convert a YUV image to a grayscale bitmap *(I believe you want grayscale, not monochrome b/w bitmap after all)*. You can find many code samples that produce the result you need. You may use this one: [Converting preview frame to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768165/android-problem-whith-converting-preview-frame-to-bitmap).