# Android decodeYUV420SP results in green images?

Tags: android, android-camera, face-detection

Ok so my question is pretty much identical to this:
[Converting preview frame to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768165/android-problem-whith-converting-preview-frame-to-bitmap)

However his answer is no good, and trying to use it doesn't solve my problem.

So what I'm trying to do at the moment is to send each frame as a bitmap to a method to detect if there are any faces, but first I need to create a bitmap which means I have to use the decodeYUV420sp method, which doesn't seem to be working properly and all my images just come out as a green and yellow tie dye looking image. Here is my code:

This is from onPreviewFrame:

```
    Parameters parameters = cam.getParameters(); 

    Integer width = parameters.getPreviewSize().width;
    Integer height = parameters.getPreviewSize().height;

    Log.i("preview size: ", String.valueOf(width) + "x" + String.valueOf(height));
    int[] mIntArray = new int[width*height];

    // Decode Yuv data to integer array
    decodeYUV420SP(mIntArray, data, width, height);

    //Initialize the bitmap, with the replaced color  
    Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(mIntArray, width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  

    saveImage(bmp);
```

This is decodeYUV method:

```
    static public void decodeYUV420SP(int[] rgba, byte[] yuv420sp, int width,
        int height) {
    final int frameSize = width * height;

    for (int j = 0, yp = 0; j < height; j++) {
        int uvp = frameSize + (j >> 1) * width, u = 0, v = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < width; i++, yp++) {
            int y = (0xff & ((int) yuv420sp[yp])) - 16;
            if (y < 0)
                y = 0;
            if ((i & 1) == 0) {
                v = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
                u = (0xff & yuv420sp[uvp++]) - 128;
            }

            int y1192 = 1192 * y;
            int r = (y1192 + 1634 * v);
            int g = (y1192 - 833 * v - 400 * u);
            int b = (y1192 + 2066 * u);

            if (r < 0)
                r = 0;
            else if (r > 262143)
                r = 262143;
            if (g < 0)
                g = 0;
            else if (g > 262143)
                g = 262143;
            if (b < 0)
                b = 0;
            else if (b > 262143)
                b = 262143;

            // rgb[yp] = 0xff000000 | ((r << 6) & 0xff0000) | ((g >> 2) &
            // 0xff00) | ((b >> 10) & 0xff);
            // rgba, divide 2^10 ( >> 10)
            rgba[yp] = ((r << 14) & 0xff000000) | ((g << 6) & 0xff0000)
                    | ((b >> 2) | 0xff00);
        }
    }
    }
```

and this is the method I'm calling to save the bitmaps to see what they look like:

```
       private void saveImage(Bitmap bmp) {

      File myDir=new File("/sdcard/saved_images");
      myDir.mkdirs();
      Random generator = new Random();
      int n = 10000;
      n = generator.nextInt(n);
      String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
      File file = new File (myDir, fname);
      if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
      try {
           FileOutputStream   out = new FileOutputStream(file);
           bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
           out.flush();
           out.close();

       } catch (Exception e) {
           e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
```

Here is a resulting image:
https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1kyIvb4oHHInW_c71mjfFSVCxVopBgBWX3k1OR_nMgRA/edit

Comment: Also I cannot get around this via: parameters.setPreviewFormat(ImageFormat.RGB_565); this is not supported in my samsung nexus.

Comment: Ok so the problem was the decodeYUV method which I got from a different stackoverflow post here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325861/converting-yuv-rgbimage-processing-yuv-during-onpreviewframe-in-android didn't quite work.

But I replaced that with what I think must be the original decodeYUV method from here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=823
And the images come up normal.

Comment: Good, so the question is resolved now? Please add [closed]e the subject to reflect this!

Comment: BTW, Android face recognition works on grayscale only, so you can improve your performance by ignoring u,v values and setting the r,g,b components of every pixel to the y value.

Comment: thanks, I am also too low reputation to answer my own question and resolve it for another few hours so will do as soon as I can

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so the problem was the decodeYUV method which I got from a different stackoverflow post here: 
[Converting YUV->RGB(Image processing)->YUV during onPreviewFrame in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325861/converting-yuv-rgbimage-processing-yuv-during-onpreviewframe-in-android) didn't quite work.

But I replaced that with what I think must be the original decodeYUV method from here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=823
an

Answer (score 1):

The key point here is that there are a (large) number of different YUV encodings, and an even larger list of names used for them. A lot of information about all the different variants (and their names) is given by [fourcc](http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php), although 420SP isn't mentionned explicitly. Looking [here](http://www.cnblogs.com/azraelly/archive/2013/01/01/2841269.html), it looks like:

- 420P is the same as YV12. 'P' appears to stand for planar: there are three 'planes' of data one after the other: Y, U and then V. (Or, in YV21, which is also a 420P encoding, Y, V and then U.)
- 420SP is the same as NV12 (which is the same as [NV21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768165/android-problem-whith-converting-preview-frame-to-bitmap) but with U and V swapped around). 'SP' appears to stand for 'semi-planar', and so '420SP' could, technically, refer to either NV21 or NV12.

In this case, therefore, you are decoding NV12 (as opposed to NV21) and so the order of U and V is swapped around compared to [the answer you quote in your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768165/android-problem-whith-converting-preview-frame-to-bitmap). In case it helps, [I have provided some code here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325861/converting-yuv-rgbimage-processing-yuv-during-onpreviewframe-in-android).