# Problem in real time face detection using firebase ML KIT

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-mlkit

As per the guide by the Firebase ML KIT and my understanding, we need to grab each frame and convert it into an image or bitmap and then make a    `FireBaseVision` image object and send it to the detector. But my code crashes after the    OnPreviewFrame    copies to a bitmap object( got this from here [Converting preview frame to bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768165/converting-preview-frame-to-bitmap))  and when I send that bitmap to the    `FirebaseVisionImage image = FirebaseVisionImage.fromBitmap(bitmap);`    so can anyone tell me what am I supposed to do. I also want to basically overlay a graphic on face detection in real time you know like snapchat etc